# Posting values to golang via curl request in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, curl, go

This is my curl post from php.This works perfectly

```
extract($postFieldsArr);
$json_id = json_encode($postFieldsArr);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://localhost:9000/GoogleSimpleReports');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_id))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Similarly i  am trying to perform a curl post from javascript to golang, is this the correct syntax ? How do i set this setRequestHeader Authorization ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:9000/GoogleSimpleReports',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 6QXNMEMFHNY4FJ5ELNFMP5KRW52WFXN5")
        }, success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            //process the JSON data etc
        }
})
```

Comment: So what's exactly your problem? Sorry but I am trying to understand your question. Do you wish to validate authorization header within golang ( https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.BasicAuth )?

Comment: Assume golang is running as a server instance port 9000, i have my website file running in apache server port 6060 separately, when i make a curl request from my website (php) to golang it works. But when i try that same curl post from my website(javascript) to golang im not sure about the syntax . i need some help regarding curl post from javascript to golang server..

Comment: The same thing you have there should work. Tho there's one thing, you can replace this beforeSend Authorization with just 'username' and 'password'. You can see settings description about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

To set the request header you have to use the [`Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) function which provide a `Get()` function accepting a `key` and a `value` as parameter.

```
func (h Header) Set(key, value string)
```

To setup the request header you should use:

```
writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

where `writer` is of type [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP).

Comment: but where do i get this key value ? can you post an example ?@ Simo